# function constructor: assign constructor

Tags: javascript, constructor

Why does the following code print "result":

```
function Person(){
    this.name = name; 
}

Person2 = Person; 

var person2 = new Person2("Jane"); 
console.log(person2.name); //result
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bcyj3e8u/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to add the parameter in the constructor:

```
function Person(name){ // <-- here
    this.name = name; 
}

Person2 = Person; 

var person2 = new Person2("Jane"); 
console.log(person2.name);
```

UPDATE: I omitted it because I thought it was not relevant (and kinda obvious), but "result" is assigned because there is a global variable in that fiddle page named "name" with the value "result" already assigned.

Comment: Ouch, haven't slept well I guess... :-) Accept in a few minutes.

Comment: if `name` is not passed then it should console `undefined`. The question is why it console `result`.

Comment: @intekhab Since the code isn't complete, there is something assinged to a `var name = 'blah';` before the function. Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/oa5ugmo4/

Answer (score 1):

It does not (in general). In your particular Fiddle, there appears to be a global `name` variable, which you're assigning to `this.name`, which happens to have the value "result". This does not happen in "clean" environments. There it prints `undefined`.

The root cause is your missing parameter in the constructor:

```
function Person(name) {
    this.name = name; 
}
```

Comment: I agree, something got corrupted in my fiddle environment. Upvote, I'll accept Pablo's answer. (he was first, and it was just a matter of forgetting the parameter).